# Yaml file for airflow which fits 1.25

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I have following version of compose:

```
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
docker-py version: 4.1.0
CPython version: 3.7.5
```

There is no possibility to update that `docker-compose` as its belong to `asustor NAS server` - at least for time being i do not know how to update it to `docker compose 2.0`. If i would my `.yaml` file would work - i chceked that on ym local `PC`. Knowing that i need to change my current `yaml` file to fits `docker-compose 1.25` and that's how it looks below. Can anyone tell me what should i change in it to avoid getting such issue running: `docker-compose up`

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:master-python3.8
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# AIRFLOW_GID                  - Group ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 0
#
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.3}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    
  postgres-test:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "test"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    # Notice I don't even use a volume here since I don't care to persist test data between runs
    
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.1.0
        min_airlfow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airlfow_version_comparable )); then
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow these instructions to set AIRFLOW_UID and AIRFLOW_GID environment variables:
            https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment"
          exit 1
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:${AIRFLOW_GID}" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:${AIRFLOW_GID:-0}"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at one of the previous versions of docker-compose we provided. I think https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/start/docker.html was the earliest one.

You will likely need to modify it as well, but I think that one was very simple without the health-checks and additional features added in more recent versions of docker-compose.

But for docker-compose, I am afraid if you want to use it, you must learn how to modify and diagnose it on your own. Unfortunately docker-compose will rarely work "out-of-the-box" and often you have to modify it as you see fit (and you need to learn it a bit).